# Can I migrate this question about the divergence of an infinite product to Mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, math-stackexchange

I thought [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679301/does-a-n-prodn-k-11-ek-alpha-pi-i-converge-to-zero-when-alpha-is) was just an homework-level but it turned out neither two of my professors in the area of analysis nor users active in mathstackexchange could give me a complete solution. The user A.S. gave his idea of proof in the comment but I don't know if his idea and conclusion is correct or not. I don't know how to convert his idea into a formal proof and he hasn't reply my further question.

I wonder if my question is a research level one and whether I can migrate it to mathoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I think your question is suitable for MathOverflow.